# how can I rewrite url without changing url in the browser with nginx

Tags: wordpress, nginx, subdomain

I have a static page in my wordpress,

https://www.mrtrobotics.com/naplan

and I would like to use subdomain for this page

edu.mrtrobotics.com

now when I use edu.mrtrobotics.com ---> it goes to https://www.mrtrobotics.com/naplan

but it shows in the url of browser as https://www.mrtrobotics.com/naplan

I want it to be shown as edu.mrtrobotics.com to user.

what should I do ??

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name mrtrobotics.com www.mrtrobotics.com;

    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        allow all;
        root /var/www/html;
    }

    location / {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name edu.mrtrobotics.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mrtrobotics.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mrtrobotics.com/privkey.pem;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

    rewrite ^ https://mrtrobotics.com/naplan permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name mrtrobotics.com www.mrtrobotics.com;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    root /var/www/html;

    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mrtrobotics.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mrtrobotics.com/privkey.pem;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
    add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
    # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
    # enable strict transport security only if you understand the implications

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off; access_log off;
    }
    location = /robots.txt {
        log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all;
    }
    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}

# Set client upload size - 100Mbyte
client_max_body_size 100M;

# to avoid 504 time out error - defalut is 60s
proxy_send_timeout 180s;
proxy_read_timeout 180s;
fastcgi_send_timeout 180s;
fastcgi_read_timeout 180s;
```

Comment: do you really need need to rewrite? if its ok you can just replace `root /var/www/html;` to `root /var/www/html/PATH_TO_APP/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server that handles edu.mrtrobotics.com should not have that rewrite rule, once you do a permanent rewrite you will send a 301 back to the browser and the URL will change. If /naplan really is the only thing that should be served from the edu subdomain, then perhaps you want something like this?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name edu.mrtrobotics.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mrtrobotics.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mrtrobotics.com/privkey.pem;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    root /var/www/html;

    location / {
        try_files /naplan/$uri /naplan =404;
    }
}
```

*Update*, as /naplan is a folder, try...

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name edu.mrtrobotics.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mrtrobotics.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mrtrobotics.com/privkey.pem;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    root /var/www/html;

    location / {
        root /var/www/html/naplan;
    }
}
```

Good luck :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.... I have tried but it did not work. I've got 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: sorry I should have included =404 as the last argument to try_files

Comment: I've sent a request to your server and /naplan is a folder, so just set the root location to /var/www/html/naplan for the edu domain.

Comment: I think I am almost there, but now I have 403 forbidden error. folder is 755, and a index.php in the folder is 644